# How to select a single cell after edit commit?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Im trying to make a time recording for tasks. The tasks are displayed in a JavaFX TableView. I made the TableView editable so the user can just doubleclick a single cell an can change the values. So now im trying to customize the selections after you hit enter. For example if you are done with the name of a task, I want to reselect the same single cell. Thats what I am struggleing with.

I've tried to get the cell through the SelectionModel.
I've tried getting the TablePosition of the cell im in.
I also tried using the FocusModel, but ended up just focusing instead of selecting the cell. (obviously)

```
@FXML
private TableView<Task> taskTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, Task> taskTableColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, String> durationTableColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, String> descriptionTableColumn;


public class TaskController {

   taskTableColumn.setOnEditCommit(e -> {

// Selection Mode is Single, dont worry
   Task selectedTask = taskTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

// 'Edit the cell value' code, not necessary for this

    taskTableView.getSelectionModel().select(selectedTask);

   }

}
```

I expected the cell to be selected again because I have the property on single selection. But it turned out to just select the last cell in a row.

Edit: This didnt work out for me too.

```
int selectedIndex = taskEntryTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
taskEntryTableView.getSelectionModel().select(selectedIndex);
```

An idea came up on me, but im not sure if this is possible. Since it looks like the methods I tried befor just select the row, is it possible to get the other position from the column?

Comment: you can edit the question to add details :) Which you must anyway, to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks, im new to the forum, I dont know the tools yet :)

Comment: Im not quite sure if I can, because I dont know half of what im doing. Im trying to get into it. There is just a main opening the controller and a fxml file. But I already cut out much in the code above to make it small and understandable. So I dont think the entire fxml file helps. I used Scenebuilder to build it btw.

Comment: removed the solved tag - we know it is because it has an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself, was not that hard now where I got it (^^):

```
@FXML
private TableView<Task> taskTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, Task> taskTableColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, String> durationTableColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, String> descriptionTableColumn;


public class TaskController {

   taskTableColumn.setOnEditCommit(e -> {

// Selection Mode is Single, dont worry
   Task selectedTask = taskTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

// 'Edit the cell value' code, not necessary for this

// the "selectedTask" just actually just contains the row, by mentioning the column itself, it gets the x and y position. 
    taskTableView.getSelectionModel().select(selectedTask, taskTableColumn);

   }

}
```

Comment: I want to convey that line `Task selectedTask = taskTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` should be replaced with `int selectedTask = taskTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();` for this to work.